# Auto scroll on drag - Vaadin DragDrop add-on

Tags: java, html, css, vaadin

I have a fixed position CssLayout with a DDVerticalLayout child component.  I'm populating this vertical layout dynamically based on user interaction to create a list view.  I run into a problem when the list becomes larger than the displayed area.  It scrolls correctly but the drag doesn't auto scroll.  This forces users to drag, scroll, drag, scroll, drag...

For example, if I selected an item at the bottom of the list and the view only displays 6 items at a time, I can't drag it more than 5 spaces up at a single time.  The view doesn't auto scroll based on the mouse hover.

[image: Scroll Example]

Parent CssLayout with child DDVerticalLayout CSS:

```
.list {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  right: 1%;
  top: 20%;
  max-width: 25%;
  max-height: 70%;
  min-height: 150px;

  .v-verticallayout {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    max-height: 350px;
    min-height: 100px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  }
}
```

DDVerticalLayout setup within CssLayout class:

```
private final DDVerticalLayout layout = new DDVerticalLayout();
//...
layout.setDragMode(LayoutDragMode.CLONE);
layout.setSizeUndefined();
layout.setDropHandler(new DefaultVerticalLayoutDropHandler()     
       @Override
        protected void handleComponentReordering(DragAndDropEvent event) {
            super.handleComponentReordering(event);
            //custom code omitted
        }
    });
```

I'm using the [drag and drop add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/dragdroplayouts) v1.3.2 for Vaadin v7.7.6.

Comment: Not tested myself, but perhaps this one helps? https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/dndscroll-add-on

Comment: it looks like that add-on is just for Table or Panel layouts.

Answer (score 2):

Its an old post but may be useful for someone else come across this issue.
You need to wrap your VerticalLayout in a Panel in order to use the DNDScroll add-on. Something like this -

```
Panel panel = new Panel();
panel.setContent(content);
panel.setHeight(200, Unit.PIXELS); //optional - could be setSizeFull();
PanelAutoScrollExtension extension = new PanelAutoScrollExtension();
extension.extend(panel);
```